# Filtering a scope with multiple select in AngularJS

Tags: select, filter, angularjs, controller, scope

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mwrLc/12/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<select ng-model="searchCountries" ng-options="cc.country for cc in countriesList | orderBy:'country'">
    <option value="">Country...</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="searchCities" ng-options="ci.city for ci in citiesList | filter:searchCountries | orderBy:'city'">
    <option value="">City...</option>
</select>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in list | filter:searchCountries | filter:searchCities">
        <p>{{item.country}}</p>
        <p>{{item.city}}</p>
        <p>{{item.pop}}</p>
        <br>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The first select filters the second one but also the result list.
The second select filters only the result list.
It works great until a country and a city are chosen. Then, when you choose another country, second select got reseted but the scope seems to be stuck with the old value.

i cant find a way to have it works properly... Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to reset the city model when a change to country model is detected via `$scope.$watch()`:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    // ...

    $scope.$watch('searchCountry', function() {
        $scope.searchCity = null;
    });
}
```

Note that I changed your model names to singular form ("searchCountry" and "searchCity") which is more appropriate considering the value of those models is set to a single country or city.

Here is the full working example: http://jsfiddle.net/evictor/mwrLc/13/

Comment: Indeed, this is the solution. I tried it, but it doesnt work with JQM and JQMA adapter installed... I can't figure out why. Angular and JQM really do not fit well together. Works well without JQM thow.

Comment: Could you post a fiddle or another question? I'd be curious to see what JQM is doing to mess it up!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mwrLc/17/ Here it is. As you can see, the second selector never reset, can't figure out why... Must be an issue from the adaptor.

Comment: My renaming of searchCountries => searchCountry and searchCities => searchCity threw you off. You pasted my snippet in but did not rename the models accordingly everywhere else. Here is the fixed fiddle using your original model names: http://jsfiddle.net/evictor/mwrLc/18/ (though again I would advise renaming searchCountries => searchCountry, etc. for semantic correctness).

Answer (score 0):

Ezekiel Victors solution is excellent. However, I ran into a bit of a dependency injection issue while trying to get this to work when referencing the controller from an ng-include. Thanks to the help from Ben Tesser I was able to resolve the issue. Ive attached a jsfiddle that details the fix:

http://jsfiddle.net/uxtx/AXvaM/

the main difference is that you need to wrap the searchCountry/searchCity as an object and set the default value to null. Ditto for the watch.

```
  $scope.test = {
    searchCountry: null,
    searchCity: null
};
/// And your watch statement ///
    $scope.$watch('test.searchCountry', function () {
        $scope.test.searchCity =  null;
});
```

In your template you'll change all references from searchCountry/searchCity to test.searchCountry.

I hope this saves someone some time. It's trixy.